# How to bind WPF combobox selected item to a label? Both label and combobox are datagrid columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, datagrid

I want to bind SelectedItem of Combobox to  "DataGridTextColumn"  after it. I am using MVVM pattern.

```
<Datagrid>
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Left">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Name="Leftcombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Column, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColumn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Right" Binding="{Binding ElementName=Leftcombo, Path=SelectedItem.Value, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>

            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, but why is your binding path `SelectedItem.Value`, does the object have a property `Value`? if you just want the selected item, use SelectedItem:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Right" Binding="{Binding ElementName=Leftcombo, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Oh wait what the heck is your `ComboBox`'s ItemSource, you only need the binding on your `DataGridTextColumn` to read the currently selected item of the `ComboBox`, your `ComboBox` should be bound to a list of items, e.g.:

```
<ComboBox Name="Leftcombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection}"/>
```

Then on your ViewModel (or whatever is your `DataContext`) you have a collection of items you want displayed in your combo box, e.g.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // use ObservableCollection<T> if you want to add remove items after assigning
    private List<string> _collection;
    public List<string> Collection
    {
        get { return _collection; }
        set 
        {
            _collection = value;
            RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("Collection");
        } 
}
```

Obviously you will need set Collection, but this is going off topic...

Tip: Check the debug output window for binding errors